# Suggest Box not working for SQL

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm seeing an error when typing into a suggest box:

`Thu Dec 08 10:45:58 GMT-700 2016
Speckle models do not support distinct sorted field values. Error: Speckle models do not support distinct sorted field values.
E
Thu Dec 08 10:45:58 GMT-700 2016
Query for field suggest oracle.: (Error) : Speckle models do not support distinct sorted field values.
E
Thu Dec 08 10:45:58 GMT-700 2016
Query for field suggest oracle. failed.`

Value of the suggest is set to:
@datasource.query.filters.project._equals

and the suggestions are set to the datasource and field project. 
I have also un-checked "Value is a record" as that is an error already in the editor.

I can use a normal text box and the same value to filter the data which works fine but would prefer the ability to select from suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Support for using suggest text field with SQL is coming in the next few weeks. I will respond to this question again when it is added.

Answer (score 1):

CloudSQL support for Suggest text field is released. Please give it a try.