# suggest box appmaker drive tables

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to use suggest box for a model that is setup with drive tables.

I found this similar question, however this model is using sql
[Suggest Box not working for SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045890/suggest-box-not-working-for-sql)

When I enter a character into the suggest box - the debug logger displays:

Drive Tables models do not support distinct sorted field values. Error: Drive Tables models do not support distinct sorted field values.

Query for field suggest oracle.: (Error) : Drive Tables models do not support distinct sorted field values.

Query for field suggest oracle. failed.

---

I am able to get it working using a text box, however this does not have the addition functionality that the suggest box has.

Answer (score 1):

Drive Tables support for suggest text field with SQL is coming in the next few weeks. I'll post to this thread once it's available.

As a temporary solution you can use SuggestBox's "Value is a record" option. Please note that all field values should be distinct otherwise you'll get duplicates in results. To use the result re-bind/get value from SuggestBox.value.[FieldName].